# How to do output in a text field and import/use a module i have made

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

i new in programming. I have made this little programme in Python 3.9 and import Tkinter.
I have made a little  « test module » to import it into my « main programme » using a button and the input in a text field.

So what i want to do is : went someone write something in the upper text box and press on the button, the button get the input of the text box, use the module and put the answer into the other text box under the fist one. (or in another window, but i a text box)

I use a test module to made this programme, before using another modules, i have made and they work very well, but the result is on a terminal and i want the result on a GUI window. I made that for practicing  what i have learn, play whit my error and improve my programming in Python. But this one make my a little crazy. Thank a lot for your help and comment.

This is the test module :

'''

```
     def nameit(name):
         greeting = f"Hello {name}, comment allez-vous!"
         return greeting
```

'''

This is the main programme :

'''

```
     import tkinter
     from essaie2 import nameit


   def decoding():                                              #I Want the #nameit module use in that 
                                                                 # window #whit the button
       uncode_window = tkinter.Toplevel(app)
       uncode_window.title("Décrytage de code")
       uncode_window.geometry("640x480+750+450")
       uncode_window.config(background="#41B77F")
       lb = tkinter.Label(uncode_window, text="Votre code ici.", background="#41B77F", font= 
                         ("Courrier", 20), fg="white")    
       entry_text = tkinter.Text(uncode_window, width=60, height=10)
       uncode_window_button = tkinter.Button(uncode_window, text="Décrypter", width=15, height=2)      
                      # the button i want to use.
       output_text = tkinter.Text(uncode_window, width=60, height=10)         #the output textbox i 
                                                                   # want the #answer with nameit use.
       uncode_window_button_quit = tkinter.Button(uncode_window, text="Quitter", width=15, height=2,   
                                                  command=uncode_window.destroy)

       lb.pack(pady=25)
       entry_text.pack()
       uncode_window_button.pack()
       output_text.pack()
       uncode_window_button_quit.pack(side="bottom")


   def wrote_code():                                          #I Want the #nameit module use in 
                                                                 # that #window whit the button
       text_writting = tkinter.Toplevel(app)
       text_writting.title("Encryptage du texte")
       text_writting.geometry("640x550+650+350")
       text_writting.config(background="#41B77F")
       lb = tkinter.Label(text_writting, text="Votre texte ici.", background="#41B77F", font= 
                         ("Courrier", 20), fg="white")
       entry_text = tkinter.Text(text_writting, width=60, height=9)
       text_writting_button = tkinter.Button(text_writting, text="Crypter", width=15, height=2)             
                                                                          #the button i want to use.
       output_text = tkinter.Text(text_writting, width=60, height=9)    #the #output textbox i 
                                                                    #want the #answer with nameit use.
       text_writting_button_quit = tkinter.Button(text_writting, text="Quitter", width=15, height=2, 
                                                  command=text_writting.destroy)

       lb.pack(pady=25)
       entry_text.pack()
       text_writting_button.pack(padx=50, pady=20)
       output_text.pack()
       text_writting_button_quit.pack(padx=50, pady=25)


   def info_window():
       window_info = tkinter.Toplevel(app)
       window_info.title("Information")
       window_info.geometry("300x80+875+350")
       lb = tkinter.Label(window_info, text="\n Logitiel pour crypter et décripter du text.\n 
                          Utiliser le même encodeur pour crypter et décrypter.\n Choissiez l'une des 
                          options pour débuter")lb.pack()


   def about():
      about_window = tkinter.Toplevel(app)
      about_window.title("À propos")
      about_window.geometry("250x80+900+350")
      lb = tkinter.Label(about_window, text="\n Utilitaire de crypter, décriptage\n Version 1"
                                      "\n Tout droit réserver 2021")lb.pack()


    #creation de la fenetre = parametrage
    app = tkinter.Tk()
    app.geometry("640x300+700+250")
    app.title("Crypteur / décrypteur de texte")
    app.config(background="#41B77F")
    label_title = tkinter.Label(app, text="Bienvenue sur l'application!", font=("Courrier", 30), 
    bg="#41B77F", fg="white")
    label_title.pack(padx=0, pady=55)
    label_subtitle = tkinter.Label(app, text="Amusez vous!", font=("Courrier", 25), bg="#41B77F", 
                                   fg="white")
    label_subtitle.pack()


    #Widgets...
    mainmenu = tkinter.Menu(app)

    files_menu = tkinter.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    files_menu.add_command(label="Copie")                   #not configurated for now.
    files_menu.add_command(label="Coller")                  #not configurated for now
    files_menu.add_command(label="Couper")                  #not configurated for now
    files_menu.add_separator()
    files_menu.add_command(label="Quitter", command=app.quit)

    edition_menu = tkinter.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    edition_menu.add_command(label="Coder un texte", command=wrote_code)
    edition_menu.add_command(label="Lire un code", command=decoding)
    help_menu = tkinter.Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    help_menu.add_command(label="Info", command=info_window)
    help_menu.add_command(label="À propos", command=about)

    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Fichier", menu=files_menu)
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Edition", menu=edition_menu)
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="?", menu=help_menu)

    # Boucle principal
    app.config(menu=mainmenu)
    app.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: Ok i have fond a way to do it. i made a line code to save it in a .txt on the deck top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the entry a variable like this `input = Entry(self)` then to get the input value use the get method like this `input.get()` and you can print it like this `print(input.get())`.

Comment: @ LublubXT, Thank. i am not sure where you tell me to put this ligne of code. I have Text box, not Entry box. Also the way i understand it this will go in the terminal, and i want it to go in the Gui output_text. This is what i have done  '''
    def summit1():
        files = [("All files", "*.*"), ("Text Document", "*.txt"), ("LibreOffice", "*.odt")]
        f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', filetype=files, defaultextension=files)
        if f is None:
            return
        text2save = nameit(str(entry_text1.get(1.0, END)))
        f.write(text2save)
        f.close()
'''

Comment: Your welcome but please don't forget to click accepted if this was the answer, it would help! It is the check mark on the side.

Answer (score 0):

ok i find a way to do it
i insert this line of code inside my function and i can save a .txt file on the desktop.
'''
def summit():
f = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".txt")
if f is None:
return
text2save = nameit(str(entry_text.get(1.0, END)))
f.write(text2save)
f.close()
'''